# Nothing happens when i click on submit button inside ajax.beginform

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using @using(Ajax.BeginForm()) in my view for posting data to controller.
but when i click on submit button, nothing happens. I am not getting any clue except the dom inspector in chrome says : 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 ... localhost/:1**

here is my code.
 In my View.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SampleAction", "UserActivity", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "DivLoginForm" }))
{

<div id="DivLoginForm">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new
   {
       Style = "width:300px;",
       PlaceHolder = "User Name",
       Id = "TxtUserId"

   })

    <input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:300px;" />

</div>
}
```

in my Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SampleAction(ViewModels.VMUser U)
    {
        string a = "";

        return View();
    }
```

In BundleConfig.cs

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Scripts").Include(
                   "~/Jquery/jquery-2.2.3.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js",
                    "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js",
                    "~/Javascripts/DefaultScript.js"));


        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke please can you help me??

Comment: The error is probably because you have not included `@Html.ValidationMesageFor(m => m.UserId)`. What do your mean nothing happens? Put a breakpoint in the `SampleAction()` method - is it being hit?

Comment: I put the break point. it is not being hit. and i added validationfor. still the problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jquery.validate are you using? I had the same problem but solved it by updating jquery.validate to the latest version. I had 1.11.1 and updated to 1.15.0.

Comment: Hi.. i solved the problem. the problem was sequence in which i had referenced all scripts.

Thank you... :)